# How can I solve this python error? PermissionError: [WinError 32]

Tags: python, python-3.x

**This is the error:**

```
os.rename(nombre_del_file_anterior, nombre_del_file_nuevo)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'contactos/alex.txt' -> 'contactos/pirata.txt'
PS C:\apps\python>
```

**this is my code:**

```
def editar_contacto():

    print('Escribe el nombre del contacto a editar')

    nombre_anterior = input('Nombre del contacto que desea editar: \r\n')

    # Revisa si el archivo existe con ese nombre, antes de editarlo 
    existe = existe_contacto(nombre_anterior)

    if existe:
        with open(CARPETA + nombre_anterior + EXT, 'w') as archivo:
            
            # Resto de los campos
            nombre_contacto = input('Agregar el nuevo nombre: \r\n')
            telefono_contacto = input('Agrega el nuevo telefono: \r\n')
            categoria_contacto = input('Agrega la nueva Categoria: \r\n')

            #Instanciar
            contacto = Contacto(nombre_contacto, telefono_contacto, categoria_contacto)

            #Escribir en el archivo
            archivo.write('Nombre:' + contacto.nombre + '\r\n') 
            archivo.write('Telefono:' + contacto.telefono + '\r\n') 
            archivo.write('Categoria:' + contacto.categoria + '\r\n')
            
            nombre_del_file_anterior = f'contactos/{nombre_anterior}.txt'
            nombre_del_file_nuevo = f'contactos/{contacto.nombre}.txt'

            #Renombrar el archivo
            os.rename(nombre_del_file_anterior, nombre_del_file_nuevo)

            #Mostrar mensaje de exito
            print(' \r\n Contacto Editado correctament \r\n ')
    else:
        print('Este contacto no existe')
```

Comment: you're trying to rename the file while it is still open. Unindent your os.rename line so it's outside the with open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def editar_contacto():

print('Escribe el nombre del contacto a editar')

nombre_anterior = input('Nombre del contacto que desea editar: \r\n')

# Revisa si el archivo existe con ese nombre, antes de editarlo 
existe = existe_contacto(nombre_anterior)

if existe:
    with open(CARPETA + nombre_anterior + EXT, 'w') as archivo:
        
        # Resto de los campos
        nombre_contacto = input('Agregar el nuevo nombre: \r\n')
        telefono_contacto = input('Agrega el nuevo telefono: \r\n')
        categoria_contacto = input('Agrega la nueva Categoria: \r\n')

        #Instanciar
        contacto = Contacto(nombre_contacto, telefono_contacto, categoria_contacto)

        #Escribir en el archivo
        archivo.write('Nombre:' + contacto.nombre + '\r\n') 
        archivo.write('Telefono:' + contacto.telefono + '\r\n') 
        archivo.write('Categoria:' + contacto.categoria + '\r\n')
        
        nombre_del_file_anterior = f'contactos/{nombre_anterior}.txt'
        nombre_del_file_nuevo = f'contactos/{contacto.nombre}.txt'

    #Renombrar el archivo
    os.rename(nombre_del_file_anterior, nombre_del_file_nuevo)

    #Mostrar mensaje de exito
    print(' \r\n Contacto Editado correctament \r\n ')
else:
    print('Este contacto no existe')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).